# Git strategy to use with white label project

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

I have a project hosted on a git environment and i have to generate a white label project based on it. I'm much more experienced with Microsoft's TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) and i know easily how i'd do that using it, but i'm unsure on how i should proceed using git.

In TFVC i would create a branch 'A' from the main project, erase any customer specific content and it's done, i have a generic version. After that i would remove the parenting, create a new branch 'B' from 'A' and then perform a baseles merge from the main project to 'B' so now i have the hierarchy i need and the newly created branch contains all the customer specific changes. As a new customer arrives, i create a branch 'C' from the generic one 'A' and apply any new changes required.

If a new feature is generic and useful enough for all clients, it will be developed in 'A' and then a merge will be done to 'B', 'C', etc. This is the best scenario since all clients will be allowed to ask for different features and toggling them on and off using a single repository, in my opinion, is far worse than maintaining different samples of code that originated from a common one. The same feature also can behave differently in different clients, and i don't want that the application has to check it at runtime.

With the scenario explained, how do i do that using Git? Also, can it be done using forks instead of branches using git?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you should generally do same things, with maybe small variations.

> create a branch 'A' from the main project, erase any customer specific content and it's done, i have a generic version.

you do same in git

> After that i would remove the parenting, create a new branch 'B' from 'A' and then perform a baseles merge from the main project to 'B' so now i have the hierarchy i need and the newly created branch contains all the customer specific changes

Instead you could start branch `B` and revert (as `git revert`) all changes which you have done to branch `A` to remove customer-specific info, thus returning to same project as you had originally, but without any manual conflict resolutions. Was it the desired result?

> As a new customer arrives, i create a branch 'C' from the generic one 'A' and apply any new changes required

same in git

> If a new feature is generic and useful enough for all clients, it will be developed in 'A' and then a merge will be done to 'B', 'C', etc

same in git

Comment: I assume, from all i read, that branches in git have a very short lifecycle and shouldn't be used in production environments, which is not true when using TFVC in the case of multiple customers. Is it considered a bad practice to use branches indefinitely?

Comment: It depends solely at your decision. You can create and remove temporary branches, but you can also make them live forever; you can also decide if you want to update them only as fast-forward or allow forceful update. In former case you would have to develop some discipline about what you pushing there because it's irreversible. For example, you you by mistake push customer-specific content to your `A` you would have to revert it, or reset to previous point before it got merged to customers' branches.

Comment: Note that those branches are supposed to mean branches at your primary server, as described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). You do not operate directly at that server, but instead use local tracking branches for development and merging, and they probably would have same names, but it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: I re-read your answer and for some reason i didn't comment on this before but the 'git revert' command wouldn't work in this case because during the development i didn't left the customer-specific content to the end of it. It was all developed concurrently, mainly because it was never meant to be used as a white label product.